# What is the provenance of this expression regarding luck

Tags: expressions

I heard the following phrase in conversation:

> "Luck is cruel to those that see it"

Is this (or a variation of) a common idiom or well known quote, and if a quote, who is attributed to it?

Comment: It does not even register any other hits in a Google search, so it can hardly be classed as an idiom (hence the adjusted title). A request for the provenance of a quote fits better with the Literature.SE site, though they have to be memorable ones. // '[Sometimes] [Lady] luck is cruel [to ...].' is reasonably common.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks evidence of research, and would be a better fit on Literature.SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about the "origin" of an expression that has no currency, and probably never did

Comment: It sounds like a variant of *Be careful what you wish for*, which is a common expression in English.  *Luck is cruel to those who see it* is probably a word-for-word translation of an expression in another language. It would be interesting to know which one.

Comment: It's another variation of *fate is a harsh mistress* or *lady luck is a fickle b—*. However, I can find no attribution for those expressions either, even though I know they are quite common in one form or another.

Comment: Failing all searches myself (no luck) I feel certain the quote must be "cruel to those that *need* it" It may be crueler to those that see it since it seems within their grasp.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I searched for 30 or so minutes with no results thus the posting on this site.

Comment: I wasn't sure of best SE site. https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10886/i-have-a-question-but-its-off-topic-where-else-could-i-ask quotes "There should also be something that says that some ostensibly off-topic questions (that are considered on-topic just by the culture here (maybe editing and adding to the following is enough):...
    provenance of proverbs or idioms - eg "Who said 'Even the devil can quote scripture' first?"" thus the post on this site.

Comment: Happy to close the question if in fact this isn't a common expression.

Comment: 'It lacks _evidence_ of research.' Searching for 30 minutes with no results almost demands that it can't be an idiom (a common expression using structure pushing the boundaries of normal grammar, or uncommon word-sense [or both]). And hints strongly that it is very uncommon. // Note that you don't mention where this statement comes from. If it is in Shakespeare's works, it is worth people here researching its history; however, if you made it up yourself ....